# Who liked me back?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table to users like another users.

I would like to get users who liked me back.

So I tried:

```
select c.user, h.id 
from heart h
left join heart hh 
    on hh.heart = h.user
left join users c 
    on h.heart = c.id // to get the user nick name
where h.user = '1' and hh.user = h.heart
```

heart table:

```
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // who is liking
  `heart` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // who is liked
```

it works for one side, showing both liked it other correctly but don't work for the other user. any ideas why? or any ideas to improve it?

eg.

> user 1 like user 2
>
> user 2 like user 1 = match = show for both.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: As to your own query: You seem to want `where (h.user = 1 or h.heart = 1)`.

Comment: Remarks: 1) Don't use `left join` when you don't want a left outer join. You want inner joins here. 2) Why `h.user = '1'`? Is this a string column? Looks like numeric to me. Hence: `h.user = 1`. 3) `and hh.user = h.heart` is part of the join criteria and should hence be moved to the `ON` clause. 4) You should be more consistent with your column names. One time `user` is a name, another time `user` is an ID. The columns in your heart table could be named `user_id_liking` and `user_ud_liked` for instance to get this more readable. `users.user` should better be `users.name` or `users.nickname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm user #1. Who likes me back (i.e. I like them, they like me)?**

In standard SQL this is a simple intersect query:

```
select heart from heart where user = 1
intersect
select user from heart where heart = 1;
```

MySQL doesn't support `INTERSECT` however. So make one query the main query, the other a lookup subquery:

```
select heart
from heart 
where user = 1
and heart in (select user from heart where heart = 1);
```

or

```
select user
from heart 
where heart = 1
and user in (select heart from heart where user = 1);
```

**In general: Who is liked back (i.e. likes someone who likes them)?**

```
select user
from heart h1
and exists
(
  select * 
  from heart h2
  where h2.user = h1.heart
    and h2.heart = h1.user
);
```

**In general again: Who is liked back by whom?**

```
select user, heart
from heart
where (user, heart) in (select heart, user from heart);
```

Answer (score 1):

If looking for who liked user with id 1:

```
select c.user, c.id 
from heart h
inner join users c 
    on h.heart = c.id // to get the user nick name
where h.user = 1;
```

Edit:

```
SELECT h1.* FROM heart h1
INNER JOIN heart h2 ON h1.[user] = h2.heart AND exists (
      select * from heart h3
      where h1.[heart] = h2.[user]
    );
```

Comment: I dont want to show who liked user 1. I want to show matches.eg: if user 1 like user 2 and user 2 like user 1. so I'll show for both that there is a match.

Comment: OK will edit, your question is not clear. Maybe you should provide sample.